# C++ How do I pass a list of non-consts to a function wanting a list of consts

Tags: c++, constants, covariance

I have a function with a signature

```
void Foo(list<const A*>)
```

and I want to pass it a

```
list<A*>
```

How do I do this?
(plz note - the list isn't constant, only the member of the list)

Comment: Did you try passing the list just as it is? If so, what did you get?

Comment: @Oswald, some horrible template casting error

Comment: Something like `error: conversion from ‘std::list<A*, std::allocator<A*> >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::list<const A*, std::allocator<const A*> >’ requested` ?

Comment: @vondip- Can you give us the error message?  Also, is this a template function, or is A a concrete type?  Finally, you're sure that you're passing by value and not by reference, right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem you have is that even though `T *` can be implicitly converted to a `T const *`, the template system isn't "aware" of that, so a `whatever<T *>` and `whatever<T const *>` are completely unrelated types, and there's no implicit conversion from one to the other.

To avoid the problem, I'd probably avoid passing a collection at all. Instead I'd have the function take a pair of iterators. A `list<A *>::iterator` *can* be implicitly converted to a `list<A *>::const_iterator`. For that matter, I'd probably make the function a template, so it can take iterators of arbitrary type.

This is likely to save you quite a bit of trouble -- a `list` is only rarely a good choice of container, so there's a very large chance that someday you'll want to change from `list<A *>` to `vector<A *>` or perhaps `deque<A *>` -- and if you make your function generic, you'll be able to do that without rewriting the function at all.

Comment: Good advice on using iterators. However, there is no relation between `list<A*>::iterator` and `list<A const*>::iterator` (or `const_iterator`), so a function taking iterators must be taking them as template parameters.

Comment: And if the function signature cannot be changed, copying from the list<A*> into a new list<const A*> would be the only solution?

Comment: @Oswald: probably a `reinterpret_cast` will work in this very special case. However there is no clean solution except abstracting away the list via iterators. In C# 4 you have covariant generics, which solve these kinds of problems quite elegantly (and open the door to powerful abstractions).

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new list and populate it with the values from your original list.  Perhaps not the most efficient solution as far as run-time and memory management is concerned, but certainly easy to code:

```
list<A*> list1;
list<const A*> list2;
for(list<A*>::iterator a=list1.begin(); a!=list1.end(); a++) list2.push_back(*a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a copy of the list - it's a pass-by-value argument. There's a fairly simple way to create a copy, since the element types have an implicit conversion: all STL containers can be created from a pair of iterators. So, in your case:

```
std::list<A*> src;
Foo(std::list<const A*>(src.begin(), src.end()));
```

This is slightly harder than it needs to be, because the STL represents ranges as pairs of iterators, and C++ conversion rules work on single objects.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you can pass it as it is. Remember that non-const types can be passed to something expecting a const type, but not the other way round!

Comment: don't be discouraged. list<A const *> and list<A *> are actually two different non-const types.